# ANT is not calling JUnits

Tags: java, ant, junit

I am new to ANT and I am trying to call Junit tests using ant (The example I use is very simple mentioned in this post). The problem is I don't see the test cases are called as I see no relevant output on the screen. (In the below message there is no log after Junit e.g. how many tests have passed )

```
Buildfile: C:\AntTestCases\build.xml
junit:
main:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 271 milliseconds
```

**build.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="testingAnt" basedir="." default="main">

<!-- classpaths -->
<path id="classpath">
        <fileset dir="lib" includes="**/*.jar"/>
</path>

<target name="junit">
        <junit printsummary="on" fork="true" haltonfailure="yes">
             <classpath>
                 <path refid="classpath"/>
             </classpath>
          <batchtest todir="reportDir">
            <fileset dir="tests" includes="*Test.java"/>
          </batchtest>
         <formatter type="xml"/>
        <formatter type="plain" usefile="false" />
        </junit>
</target>

<target name="main" depends="junit"/>
</project>
```

[image: directory structure]

**Test class**

```
package suite;
import org.junit.Test;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class SampleTests extends TestCase{
    @Test
    public void test1()  {
        System.out.println("SampleTests.test1()");
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

I will really appreciate your input of where I am going wrong. I have read few tutorials about junit with ant but nothing  is helping
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/ApacheAnt/article.html
http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html

Version of Junit is 4, ant - 1.8.1 and java 1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to something like

```
      <batchtest todir="reportDir">
        <fileset dir="tests" includes="**/*Test.java"/>
      </batchtest>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for finding the mistake!